# Show, with the definition, that $\lim_{ (x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{(2x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-3x^2y^4-3y^6)}{(x^2+y^2)}$ exist.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Show with the definition that $\lim_{ (x,y) \to(0,0)}
> \frac{(2x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-3x^2y^4-3y^6)}{(x^2+y^2)}$ exist.

I think that this limit exists and it is equal to $0$. What I have done so far is $$||\frac{(2x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-3x^2y^4-3y^6)}{(x^2+y^2)}|| = ||\frac{2x^2||\alpha||^2+y^4(1-3||\alpha||^2)}{||\alpha||^2}||$$ $$=||\frac{2x^2||\alpha||^2-y^4(3||\alpha||^2-1)}{||\alpha||^2}|| \leq ||\frac{2x^2||\alpha||^2+y^4(3||\alpha||^2-1)}{||\alpha||^2}|| \leq$$ $$||\frac{2x^2||\alpha||^2+y^4(3||\alpha||^2)}{||\alpha||^2}|| = ||2x^2+3y^4||$$ where $\alpha =(x,y)$. I would like to use the fact that $||\alpha||< \delta$, but I'm blocked actually.

Is anyone is able to give me a good hint to advance my problem?

Comment: $|x|\leq \alpha \geq |y|$ so $\|2 x^2+3 y^4\|\leq 2\alpha^2+\alpha^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(2x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-3x^2y^4-3y^6)}{(x^2+y^2)}=2x^2-3y^4+\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}$$

Enough to prove $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}$ exists

See that $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}\leq (x^2+y^2)$..

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Could you explain the inequality $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}\leq (x^2+y^2)...$?

Comment: That is one of the very basic inequalities and i prefer not to say anything about that.. Please give some try...

Comment: Yes, but I try since you put the response to my question. I don't find this inequalities

Comment: Do you at least see that $b^2\leq (a+b)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^2+y^2.$ Use $x^2,y^2\le u$ to see the absolute value of our expression is

$$\le \frac{2u^2 +2u^2+u^2 + 3uu^2 +3u^3}{u} = \frac{5u^2 + 6u^3}{u}= 5u+6u^2\to 0.$$